# prepareForSegue not opening ViewController

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I currently have this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    print("Being called: PrepareForSegue")

    if(segue.identifier == "FBLoggedInSegue"){
        print("Identifier: FBLoggedInSegue")
        let nextVC = (segue.destinationViewController as? FBFriendsController)!
        nextVC.accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
        print("Niks gebeurd")
    }
}
```

The console actually shows all of the print statements within my if statement. Unfortunately, the prepareForSegue will not open the `FBFriendsController`.

This is the code I am running in the `viewDidLoad()` function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("FBLoggedInSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the performSegue from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are 100% certain of segue.identifier: Modify `print("Identifier: FBLoggedInSegue")` to display the actual identifier, otherwise you are working off assumptions.

Have you set the ID on the view you wish to segue to **or** or the actual segue line in the Interface Builder?

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:** 
Do this:
`let vc : YourViewController
storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FBLoggedInSegue") as
YourViewController
vc.accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)`

It seems the issue was present as the view controller was not getting allocated :)

Comment: I have clicked the segue itself (a show segue between the first and second controller), then gave it an identifier. So that should work well, right?

Comment: I am not a swift expert, but thats how I would do it in Obj-C. Had any luck?

Comment: I changed to check for the `segue.identifier!` as it is an `Optional`. It still lands into the if statement, printing the right code..
I did check for certainty on segue.identifier by `print(segue.identifier!)`.

Still not changing ViewControllers, though.

Comment: Try this in your `viewDidLoad`: `let vc : YourViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FBLoggedInSegue") as YourViewController` `vc.accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` `self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)`

Comment: Of course I will vote it up and accept it as the answer :)